# Docker won't start after system freeze

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

Been trying to solve this for the past half of the day and I am facing brick wall at this point, first of all, what happened:
I was using my machine as usual and it suddenly froze, I had to hard-restart my laptop with a power button, while I had one of my docker containers up.

After restarting I cannot up my docker-composer container anymore, using `sudo docker-compose up -d` this is what I get

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

I searched google and tried different offered methods including:

- Re-installing docker X times
- Adding user to a group
- Trying to up docker-composer with both sudo and without it
- Stopping and starting docker service
- systemctl commands associated with docker
- A bunch of other solutions I found

If I try to run for example `docker info` I get the following:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

This happens for all of the commands associated with docker. This is what I get if I run `service docker status` :

```
Active: inactive (dead)

Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

My best guess is that once my system halted and I restarted it without stopping docker, it is still running somewhere behind the scenes and I must find a way to kill it? Although then I am not sure if I already deleted docker and re-installed it, shouldn't this solve the "mysterious process in the background" issue?

At this point I am only thinking about using older image of my Ubuntu 16.04 which I am not even sure will work, but I am out of ideas at this point, would be very grateful if someone would help me out here. If you need any additional info, just let me know and I will edit this post.

EDIT: Info from /var/log/upstart/docker.log

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
/var/run/docker.sock is up
time="2017-07-13T16:01:14.278980783+03:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 2315" 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:15.947896762+03:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds" 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:15.948172349+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit" 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:15.948222431+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period" 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:15.948234045+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime" 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:15.948561160+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start." 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:16.879689640+03:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address" 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:17.277750516+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done." 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:17.920812553+03:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization" 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:17.920861773+03:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=02c1d87 graphdriver=aufs version=17.06.0-ce 
time="2017-07-13T16:01:17.927527669+03:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock" 
time="2017-07-13T16:42:40.869391999+03:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'" 
INFO[2485] stopping containerd after receiving terminated
```

Comment: Your service wouldn't keep running after you restarted. However it seems to be indeed in a corrupted state. Have you tried to uninstall Docker with the purge option before reinstalling it? Or to remove `/var/lib/docker` after having uninstalled?

Comment: Also these logs are the logs of *systemctl*. It would be interesting the find the *docker* logs that show details about what happens when you try to start the service.

Comment: @arvymetal Yes, the funny thing is that I purger my docker using http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2016/07/30/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker-from-ubuntu/ this solution and after restarting my computer, docker -v and docker-compose -v gave back versions of it.
Also, I removed /docker folder with all my containers

Comment: @arvymetal if I try to run docker logs SERVICE, I get `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
`

Comment: Yes, but this message is just a consequence of the fact that the docker service isn't starting. That's why we should find more details about why it doesn't start.

Comment: Nearly all of the commands associated with docker are un-runnable because of this "docker daemon running" thing

Comment: Yes, of course, the service is off. The *docker* executable contains both a server, and a client (the command line tool). If the server doesn't run, every client command will fail.

Comment: @arvymetal do you know where I could find docker logs for more info, because I only found this "docker logs SERVICE" option that is not working for me

Comment: Isn't there a *docker* file or directory in `/var/log`?

Comment: @arvymetal sorry completely forgot about posting info from those logs, I edited original post and pasted logs in the bottom of the post

Comment: Thanks! The bad news is that the log doesn't show so interesting things... It just shows that the service started at 16:01 and was over at 16:42, with nothing showing a failure. I couldn't say if the three warnings are important or don't prevent *Docker* from running. Are the times consistent? Or could you try to restart the service if you didn't do so (with `service up`), to be sure it represents what's going on? And a last question, Is your Ubuntu machine a VM?

Comment: Ah you have put it in your question, it's a VM.

Comment: @arvymetal I think they are consistent. 
Not sure about restarting service? Service docker restart gives back the same error from above. And no, my ubuntu is not a VM

Comment: @arvymetal I did? It is not a VM, I have Ubuntu on a seperate partition where I have Windows on other partition

Comment: Ah OK, I misinterpreted "thinking about using older image of my Ubuntu"

Comment: @arvymetal if its regarding images, when I start my laptop I can choose to boot "Advanced ubuntu" and from there I think I can go back to previous kernel, so probably I should written this instead of image

Comment: Because we'll surely be able to get rid of that issue... But if you'd prefer pragmatism, there are other options:
1) to use *Docker for Windows*, which works correctly, the Windows paths add some complexity, but I didn't meet any blocking situation, and 2) to install "Docker Toolbox" which will deploy for you a Linux virtual machine (but in this case you'll have to forward network ports in the VirtualBox UI)

Comment: Cannot do that, All my work is on my Ubuntu partition I cannot switch to Windows, this doesn't work for me so I have to find a way to fix this, but thank you for a help so far!

Comment: Maybe this answer is also on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Having an Upstart log in Ubuntu 16.04 with Systemd is strange...  You're running an older version of Docker.  The package is no longer named **docker-engine**.  It is now **docker-ce**.  The repository URL changed.

See:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Comment: Thank you for this, I completely deleted everything related to docker from my machine and I followed the documentation you provided. After installing docker-ce with :
`sudo apt-get install docker-ce`
Update ran smoothly I think, it says:
`Setting up docker-ce (17.06.0~ce-0~ubuntu) ...`
and then it crashes with [this](http://i.imgur.com/zKqrr70.png)

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep cgroup` ?

Comment: `➜  ~ dpkg -l | grep cgrou
ii  cgroupfs-mount                               1.2                                            all          Light-weight package to set up cgroupfs mounts
ii  libcgmanager0:amd64                          0.39-2ubuntu5                                  amd64        Central cgroup manager daemon (client library)
`

Comment: I use cgroup-lite.  Try purging cgroupfs-mount and installing cgroup-lite, then reboot.

Comment: I did what you said, now `dpkg -l | grep cgroup` returns
`ii  cgroup-lite                                  1.11                                           all          Light-weight package to set up cgroups at system boot
ii  libcgmanager0:amd64                          0.39-2ubuntu5                                  amd64        Central cgroup manager daemon (client library)
`
But yeah, [still the same issue](http://i.imgur.com/efqBDRq.png)

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status docker.service` ?

Comment: I noticed that I have a lot of errors while booting my pc, such as "failed to load kernel modules" so from Advanced ubuntu I loaded `4.4.0-81-generic`, which is a bit older I assume. I booted my machine without a single error , so now `systemctl status docker.service` [returns this](http://i.imgur.com/druLFsl.png)

Comment: I'm running the 4.10 kernel with no problem. Do you have the extra package of the Linux kernel installed?  In your case it would be linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic.  Which modules failed to load?

Comment: at the moment with .81 if I run `journalctl | grep modules` I get
`Lie 13 20:50:23 viktor systemd-modules-load[232]: Inserted module 'lp'
Lie 13 20:50:23 viktor systemd-modules-load[232]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Lie 13 20:50:23 viktor systemd-modules-load[232]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Lie 13 20:51:04 viktor virtualbox[1572]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...`

Comment: `dmesg | grep module`

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure docker-ce` ?